# Socket io create emit in different file?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I try today to use socket.io, and one point no clear to me.

I create socket connection function in app.js file, but I need to make also emit in another file (no frontend, this is the server file), that makes some update logic and also should do emit.

How to do emit in another file? Connect to io socket in another fils? 
Best practice? Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest following the event-driven programming as NodeJs nature is. I don't know if you are trying something related but this post https://medium.freecodecamp.org/using-events-in-node-js-the-right-way-fc50c060f23b could be more explained than me.

Comment: Oh Thank You, I forgot about node events :)